# Reverse order of sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list of coordinates

```
{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}}
```

how can this list be changed to

```
{{y1,x1},{y2,x2},{y3,x3}}
```

Comment: How about `Reverse/@list`, where `list={{x1,y1},…}`?

Comment: `List[[All,{2,1}]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}};
Reverse[list, 2]
```

> {{y1, x1}, {y2, x2}, {y3, x3}}